# CodeIgniter - Updated From 2.2.x to 3.1.4 - Getting 404 Error In Application

Tags: php, codeigniter, migration, codeigniter-3

Okay so I have a codeigniter application that I just updated from 2.2.1 to 3.1.4

I followed all instructions and made all the changes. But on my application I am getting a 404 Page Not Found.

I have updated my modules and changed all classes names to include a uppercase (included the file name). I also updated routes.php any idea why I would be getting a 404 error after upgrading?

Comment: have you changed first letter of your controller file to uppercase?

Comment: Yes, this was one of my notes in my question. I have made first letter every controller and class uppercase (including the file name).

Comment: checkfolder permissions

Comment: I had same problem, but problem is on server. On localhost - it was working fine... I am unable to findout the reason.

Comment: Maybe need new htaccess for live domain for your main directory.

Answer (score 0):

Is your htaccess file correctly configured?